# Converting VARCHAR into Numeric SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

I have this `VARCHAR` column which needs to be average.

```
 | Duration |
     5.4 s
```

How can I get rid of the letter and space to convert it into int/numeric.

Need help guys

Comment: When you say `help` it means some efforts from your side.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If all of those columns only have ' s' at the end, just ditch ' s':

```
SELECT CAST(REPLACE(Duration,' s','') as float)
```

Comment: Thanks. I try this one. Thanks bro

Comment: Yo. I try your code. but it says that "Error coverting data type varchar to float"

Comment: You have a field with values that are different than ' s'. Not all the values in that field follow this format (one of the problems with storing numbers in a varchar field)

Comment: Ohh.. Okay. But our database column here is not changeable still needs an authorize person to change it.